# return value from a callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, node.js, translate

I'm using node.js and the library  [Translate](https://github.com/Marak/translate.js) . Can i do something like this ? :

```
function traduce(text){
    translate.text(text,function(err,result){
        return result;
    });
}
```

And then use the result? It always return me "undefined". is there any way to use the result without do this? : .

```
translate.text(text,function(err,result){
     // use result
     // some logic
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example few lines of how you are hoping to use your `traduce` function?  There will probably be a way to do what you want, but in an asynchronous way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't executing the function, you are passing a reference to an anonymous function. If you want the return value, execute it:

```
function traduce(text){
    translate.text(text, (function(err,result){
        return result;
    })());
}
```

Comment: `translate.text` takes a function as its second argument

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much a question can you do that, but should you do that. It's really a matter of understanding asynchronous code, something which every introduction to node.js covers in some depth.

Translate itself uses the google api, so makes a request to another server.  If you were to wait for the result it would be a lengthy blocking operation, which is undesirable.

Answer (score -1):

They are providing translations of 30 languages. I think, that means that the translation is made by calling a webservice, right? Maybe node.js provides something like "waitFor" like in some other languages. But as you ve written it is not accomplishable